# Avoid spilling of column value to other columns while reading csv in pyspark

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, delimiter

I have a csv of 9GB and trying to read in pyspark , below is values of csv one row and column -

`|nature_of_suit|posture|syllabus|headnotes|summary|disposition|correction|doc_id|`

`| | |<p>In May, 1873, a brewer pays to the collector |100 as special tax, for which a special-lax stamp is issued to him. Subsequently, he simes lo the satisfaction of the Commissioner of Internal Tevenne that he was not a brewer of more than 500 barrels, and hence that he is entitled to have $50 refunded. The Commissioner issues his certificate for a special-tax stamp of the value of $50 returned. The Treasury ref uses payment of the certificate. The brewer brings his action to recover the amount thereof.</p> <p>Tlie court helow holds : (1) That the Commissioner, being authorized to refund taxes “unjustly assessed or excessive in amount” (Rev. Stat., §3220)- and the value of stamps “where the rates of duties represented thereby have been paid in error or remitted” (id., § 3426), it is immaterial whether his certificate was in one form or the other; (2) That the Court of Claims has jurisdiction of a case founded on the award of a revenue officer in • a matter of which he has jurisdiction and the Treasury has refused to-pay the award. Judgment for the claimant. The defendants appeal.</p> <p>The judgment of the court below is affirmed. The Supreme Court now holds: (1) That the award of the Commissioner, not being- impeached, was conclusive ; (2) That the Court of Claims has jurisdiction of such cases.</p>|<p>KAUFMAN’S CASE.</p>|<p>On the defendants1 Appeal.</p>| | |65862636|`

I tried below options -

`df=spark.read.format("csv").option("header",True).option("inferSchema",True).option("multiLine",True).load("2023-08-31.csv")`

But getting below output -

`|nature_of_suit|posture|syllabus|headnotes|summary|disposition|correction|doc_id|`

`|null          |null   |"<p>In May, 1873, a brewer pays to the collector $100 as special tax, for which a special-tax stamp is issued to Mm. Subsequently he shoivs to. the satisfaction of the Commissions)' of Internal Revenue that he was not a brewer of more than 500 barrels, and henee that he is entitled to have $50 refunded. The Commissioner issues his certificate for a special-tax stamp of the value of%50 returned. The Treasury refuses payment of the certificate. The breioe)' brings his action to recover the amount thereof.</p> <p>I. The Commissioner of Internal Revenue being authorized by one section of the statutes (Rev. Stat., § 3220) to refund taxes “unjustly assessed or excessive in, amount,"" and by another| (§ 3426 |) the value of special-tax stamps ‘‘where the rates of duties represented thereby have been paid in error or remitted|"" it is immaterial whether his certificate be in form under the one section or the other so long as it represents a case where the Commissioner is authorized to refund and the amoirnt which the party is entitled to have refunded.</p> <p>II. When a controversy under the revenue laws is by law required to be determined by other officers and other tribunals| and exhausted his jurisdiction|null     |`

The issue seems its getting split at ',' commas and hence giving wrong values in the column.

Expected output -

`|nature_of_suit|posture|syllabus|headnotes|summary|disposition|correction|doc_id|`

`|null|null|<p>In May, 1873, a brewer pays to the collector |100 as special tax, for which a special-lax stamp is issued to him. Subsequently, he simes lo the satisfaction of the Commissioner of Internal Tevenne that he was not a brewer of more than 500 barrels, and hence that he is entitled to have $50 refunded. The Commissioner issues his certificate for a special-tax stamp of the value of $50 returned. The Treasury ref uses payment of the certificate. The brewer brings his action to recover the amount thereof.</p> <p>Tlie court helow holds : (1) That the Commissioner, being authorized to refund taxes “unjustly assessed or excessive in amount” (Rev. Stat., §3220)- and the value of stamps “where the rates of duties represented thereby have been paid in error or remitted” (id., § 3426), it is immaterial whether his certificate was in one form or the other; (2) That the Court of Claims has jurisdiction of a case founded on the award of a revenue officer in • a matter of which he has jurisdiction and the Treasury has refused to-pay the award. Judgment for the claimant. The defendants appeal.</p> <p>The judgment of the court below is affirmed. The Supreme Court now holds: (1) That the award of the Commissioner, not being- impeached, was conclusive ; (2) That the Court of Claims has jurisdiction of such cases.</p>|<p>KAUFMAN’S CASE.</p>|<p>On the defendants1 Appeal.</p>|null|null|65862636|`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please try to add the delimiter as '|'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by adding:

```py
df=spark.read.format("csv").option("header",True).option("inferSchema",True).option("multiLine",True).option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"").load("2023-08-31.csv")
```